# React Formik not handling errors properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I'm using the basic Formik template to work on a Login Form.

```
onSubmit={(
                    values,
                    { setSubmitting, setErrors /* setValues and other goodies */ }
                  ) => {
                      props.logMeIn(values);
                    // LoginToSystem(values).then( 
                    //   user => {
                    //     setSubmitting(false); 

                    //     // do whatevs...
                    //     // props.updateUser(user)
                    //   },
                    //   errors => {
                    //     setSubmitting(false);
                    //     // Maybe transform your API's errors into the same shape as Formik's
                    //     //setErrors(transformMyApiErrors(errors));
                    //     console.log(errors);
                    //   }
                    // );
                }}
```

This problem is within the `onSubmit` section; The demo code is commented out but it uses a `LoginToSystem` function that seems to be a promise. I can not figure out 'what' this function is supposed to me. My function that handles this would be `props.logMeIn()` - Which also does not work *as intended*

If the login is successful, it will currently work as expected, and everything is fine. However, if the login fails (404, 401, whatever) the form will remain there, and the `setSubmitting` log stays there so Submit is grayed out but nothing is done.

If I try to replace `LoginToSystem` with my function, I get an error on the `.then` that I can't perform `.then` on `undefined`.

I'm wondering if perhaps this is because my function is not set up like a Promise?

```
  loginClickHandler = (user) => {
    let userObj = {
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password
    }
    axios.post('api/v1/auth/sign_in', userObj)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.headers);
          let loggedInUser = {
           'access_token': res.headers['access-token'],
           'client': res.headers['client'],
           'uid':res.headers['uid'],
           'signedIn': true
          };
          this.setState({
            user: loggedInUser
          })     
          this.props.retrieve(user.email);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            return err
        })

  };
```

My function does properly catch (Thanks to axios) on the .then/.catch, but perhaps I am supposed to modify those to provide a callback so that `onSubmit` can properly fire?

Answer (score 1):

With some guidance I was able to resolve this one simpler. Axios is natively returning a 'promise' so I just needed to ensure the outcome of the function was axios' method in the end.

```
 loginClickHandler = (user) => {
        let userObj = {
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password
        }
        const request = axios.post('api/v1/auth/sign_in', userObj);

        request.then((res) => {
            console.log(res.headers);
            let loggedInUser = {
                'access_token': res.headers['access-token'],
                'client': res.headers['client'],
                'uid': res.headers['uid'],
                'signedIn': true
            };
            this.setState({user: loggedInUser, auth: true, anchorEl: null})
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            // setErrors({ test: 'This was an error' })
        })
        return request;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

In **onSubmit** there's a second argument for setting your errors. I added **flow** to be able to see the types better in this answer for you.

```
<Formik
  initialValues={...}
  ... // Other Props
  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} // This is where you handle your login logic 
  render={this.renderForm}   // Render your form here.
```

You have a callback to help you set errors in the second argument

```
handleSubmit = (
  user: FormValues,
  { setErrors }: FormikActions<FormValues>
) => {
   return axios.post('api/v1/auth/sign_in', userObj)
   ... 
   .catch(e) => {
     setErrors({ username: 'Invalid Username' }) // Object you want to put here. 
   }
}
```

In your render form function you now have errors that you can use based on what you called in your setErrors

```
renderForm = ({
  ... // These are your other FormikProps you're using
  errors // You want to use this
}: FormikProps<FormValues>) => (
  ... // Your rendering here
      // errors.username 
)
```

For **flow** types on Formik 
https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/formik_v0.9.x/flow_v0.53.x-/formik_v0.9.x.js

Comment: I'm struggling to quite following with the logic. The top code block is modifying my function itself? How does it recieve `FormValues`? Also, is this in TS? I didn't know I could use types like that.

Comment: Btw I updated the answer to try and clarify. 

The types are from `flow` you would have to add it into your webpack to enable it. https://flow.org/ I added it into this answer so you can have a easier time following the code.

Comment: I realized you probably also need to return your promise in handleSubmit

Comment: Woops just noticed you made an answer about that